# How to properly set up animations from blender to UE5?

Tags: animation, transforms, unreal-engine

So, I am creating some animations for someone using UE5 and they are attaching the weapon to a socket on the mannequin. I have everything posed in blender, question is, how do I match the position of the weapon from blender to UE? There is almost NOTHING on the web about how to do this, everybody just tries to match it up by hand, but being a somewhat experienced animator this will not slide for me.

The weapon is zeroed on all axis in the base pose, and is it's own separate armature, if that is useful information.

The only thing I've been told that makes sense, is to use the 3D Cursor to detect the XYZ offset from the root bone of the weapon, to hand_r, but while it makes sense, I don't know how to execute it.

Screenshots:
[image][image]

Comment: Normally you have a rig for your character with the same camera as in your game engine, and you just match the values from one to the other. No guesswork there.